# ASP.NET MVC security and IIS allowSubDirConfig configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iis

I've got informed that following the [general Microsoft recommendation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn529134) our web servers will be reconfigured; among other things the [allowSubDirConfig setting](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/virtualdirectorydefaults) should be set to `false`. Thus, our ASP.NET applications must use a single Web.config at their root level (which is quite okay for our applications by the way).

However, ASP.NET MVC uses a "non root level" configuration file (by default!) for the `Views` directory, which contains a simple (but important?) web server related section:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
        <add name="BlockViewHandler"
            path="*"
            verb="*"
            preCondition="integratedMode"
            type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Regarding to [a post by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/25/aspnetmvc-block-view-access.aspx) this is security related, hence important.

Since the other .NET Framework related sections [still work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sroun/archive/2014/11/14/allowsubdirconfig-clarification.aspx), because the ASP.NET runtime does not obey the `allowSubDirConfig` setting, an ASP.NET MVC application still works too. So the ignored web server configuration doesn't really attract attention during general usage, although i've a bad feeling about it.

Isn't that a lousy idea? If web servers are configured that way (by recommendation), how vulnerable are those ASP.NET MVC applications out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HttpNotFoundHandler has a path attribute which means you can add it to the root config file and point path to the Views folders and you would not be altering the security level in any way:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="Views/*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

This will work with a basic web.config file, but beware if you are adding/removing handlers as part of your application. Handlers that come before the BlockViewHandler could still deliver content from the Views subfolder (but then I believe this is also the case with the standard web.config in the Views directory unless you remove the handler there specifically).

Generally speaking IIS will not serve .cshtml files from the Views folder (unless specifically allowed) even if the system.webServer section is missing/ignored in the Views subdirectory.

But it would serve other files (e.g. html,css,js) which would be blocked by the BlockViewHandler handler which could be regarded as reduced security.

Comment: Thanks, the `path` attribute helps. I removed the `BlockViewHandler` from the Views/Web.config and was able to download a .png file; with your config added to the root Web.config it's blocked again. But if the developer isn't aware of this "issue"... in short, that sucks.